# Angular 2: Custom validation for file extensions and size

Tags: angular

I have an `<input type='file>` element in my form. I want to create a custom validation for checking the file size and extension. I am using reactive `FormBuilder` and `FileReader` API for fetching file name and size of the input element field data.

**Problem**: We are able to trigger custom validation on change event but could not fetch value of input type field.

Please suggest how we can implement custom validation for file extensions and size in angularjs 2.

---

Here is my code:

#### HTML:

```html
<input type="file" (change)="changeThumbFile($event)">
```

#### Component:

```js
//custom validation
function validateExt(c: FormControl) {
    let extension = ['png', 'jpeg', 'gif'];
    return extension.indexOf(c.value)? null : { validateExt: { valid: false } }
}
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  'thumbnailImg': ['', validateExt],
});
changeThumbFile($event){
    var file: File = $event.target.files[0];
    var fReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    var imgName = file.name;
    this.thumbnailName = imgName;

    this.formGp.controls['thumbnailImg'].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Where is `thumbnailImg` in your template?